# Debugging Heapsort in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapsort

I know how to program in Java, I am very new to python. I am trying to implement HeapSort in Python but I am unable to get where this code went wrong. Can anyone help ?

This is my implementation:

```
class HeapSort:

    def sort(self,list):
        self.p = list
        self.N = len(list)
        for k in range(N/2,1,-1):
            sink(k,N)

        while N> 1:
            exch(1,N)
            N -=1
            sink(1,N)

# Helper Functions to restore the heap invariant

    def sink(k,N):
        while 2*k <= N:
            j = 2*k
            if (j<N & (j < j+1)):
                j += 1
            if (j < k):
                break
            exch(k,j)
            k = j

    def exch(i,j):
        p[i],p[j] = p[j],p[i]

# Helper Functions to debug

    def isSorted(list):
        for k in range(1,len(list)):
            return False
        return True


    L = [6, 4, 2, 8, 1, 9, 3, 0, 12, 5]
    print(L)
    h = HeapSort()
    h.sort(L)
    print(L)
```

The output I am getting is

```
[6, 4, 2, 8, 1, 9, 3, 0, 12, 5]
    NameError: "name 'HeapSort' is not defined"

    module body in heapsort.py at line 26
    class HeapSort:
    function HeapSort in heapsort.py at line 64
    h = HeapSort()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF your indentation is accurate, it is causing you to try to call HeapSort in your definition of HeapSort.

Instead you would want

```
class HeapSort():
    ...

def main():
    L = [6, 4, 2, 8, 1, 9, 3, 0, 12, 5]
    print(L)
    h = HeapSort()
    h.sort(L)
    print(L)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This allows you to run the file in which you define your class, and if other files import the class, it will not run the code.

**EDIT**

The above will fix the error that you are getting, but if you see @Matt's comments, but you are running tests *within* your `heapsort.py` file, you should move these to an external `heapsort-tests.py` file and import your class with

```
from heapsort import HeapSort
```

**EDIT 2**

If you are treating this as a class you want to use and pass around as an instantiated object, then you need to pass `self` to all of your methods and call them with `self.method_name()`, i.e. `self.sink(x,y)`. If not, you would sort by calling something like `HeapSort.sort(L)` instead of creating `h`.

Comment: He has to put the `HeapSort` class in a separate file called `heapsort.py`.

Comment: @Matt he doesn't *have* to. I have a working example of the same thing in a python 2.7 file. Did this change for 3.x?

Comment: Apologies for keeping the HW question as part of question... I deleted it

Comment: I am still getting error UnboundLocalError: "local variable 'N' referenced before assignment" But I initialized N as sort function as self.N = len(list) and since I used self it should be available all the class right ?

Comment: @sri009 that's because you assign it as a self attribute but don't use it as such. `self.N = len(list)`. You probably just want `N = len(list)` or always reference it as `self.N`. You will probably get the same problem with `p`.

Comment: @C.B. Thanks for the reply but I am now getting another error saying NameError: "global name 'sink' is not defined"

module body in heapsort.py at line 70
main()
function main in heapsort.py at line 66
h.sort(L)
function sort in heapsort.py at line 32
sink(k,N)

Comment: @sr009 see my edit. You might need to check out OO programming in python to get a flavor of what you need to do.